# Cookies sent from Springboot application is unable to store in Browser. "Set-Cookie" header is present but devtools->application->cookie Tab is empty

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, httpresponse, setcookie

Springboot backend -> sending Cookie with a token in response [image]

React frontend -> Cookie is present in the response header. [image] [image]

BUT THE BROWSER IS NOT STORING THE COOKIE. Application -> Cookie Tab is empty.

So the requests made from React app to the backend APIs are getting 401 unauthorized because the token in Cookie is not present for subsequent requests.

Testing from POSTMAN working absolutely fine. [image]

I'm looking for a solution that fixes the problem and successfully stores the Cookie in browser application tab when requesting, so that React app can make subsequent requests to the backend with the cookie without getting 401 unauthorized error.

P.s.- I know I can store the jwt Token in local storage but that is insecure and I only want to send it through backend Cookie(httpOnly)

Comment: how did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue!